# Как использовать JWT с Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Использую Retrofit для осуществления запросов к серверу и парсинга ответов. Необходимо реализовать авторизацию с использованием JWT. Как я понимаю, на некоторые запросы которые сейчас работают для всех, будет накладываться некий фильтр на наличие токена. Каким образом использовать Retrofit с JWT?

Answer (score 5):

Часто JWT передается в `header` запроса.
Вы можете добавить аннотацию `@Header`

```
@GET("secret")
Call<User> getSecret(@Header("Authorization") String token)
```

И передавать нужную строку с каждым запросом.

Так же вы можете использовать Interceptor и добавлять `header` в нем, тогда запросы можно не менять.

```
final class AuthorizationRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private String token

    public AuthorizationRequestInterceptor(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        if (originalRequest.body() == null || originalRequest.header("Authorization") != null) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }

        Request authorizedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", token)
                .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(authorizedRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: а существующие запросы нуждаются в изменении?

Comment: я добавил в ответ Interceptor. он позволяет добавлять токен во все запросы.

Comment: Для реавторизации лучше пользовать Authenticator, а не Interceptor. Иначе при параллельных запросах получите массу неприятностей с несколькими авторизациями и токенами... http://innodroid.com/blog/post/using-okhttp-authenticator

Comment: а как использовать экземпляр AuthorizationRequestInterceptor непосредственно при создании клиента Retrofit?

Comment: @SerheiIvanov я сейчас посмотрю Authenticator, переделаю ответ и добавлю как использовать.

Comment: а для первой авторизации и последующих реаторизацяих необходимо использовать Authenticator и Interceptor или Authenticator "универсален" ?

Comment: @SerheiIvanov пока не могу ответить, я еще не посмотрел.